# MySQL/PHP retrieve how many times an item also appears in a second table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

first time here ...

I have an issue in MySQL:

I have a table 'products' with some fields like product_id, itemcode, label, price, ....
There is also a second table 'inventory' that has some common fields with the first field. The field 'itemcode' is the easiest to compare both tables.

products has from every 'itemcode'-item only one appearance. Inventory, however, has them multiple times.

What I need to do:
I need to output how many times each 'itemcode' from 'products' appears in 'inventory'. What would be the best way to do so?

example

```
products
  itemcode
  AA2244G
  AB2245G
  AC2246G
  AD2247G
  AE2248G

inventory
  itemcode
  AA2244G
  AA2244G
  AB2245G
  AC2246G
  AC2246G
  AC2246G
  AE2248G

Output
 AA2244G 2x
 AB2245G 1x
 AC2246G 3x
 AD2247G 0x
 AE2248G 1x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.itemcode, CONCAT(COUNT(b.itemcode), 'x') totalCount
FROM    products a 
        LEFT JOIN inventory b
            ON a.itemcode = b.itemcode
GROUP BY a.itemcode
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3492b/3)